# Solving natbib problem for XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, captions, natbib

## Problem with referencing when natbib is used (XeLaTex)

Thank you for your time. I am using a template from my institute to write my thesis. When I run the document, it compiles alright but fails to produce references. In the places where I use \cite{*}, only question marks show in those places. I have been trying and researching for the past 24hrs, but all no avail. Please help solve this problem. While compiling, I see the following warnings:

1. Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended.See the caption package documentation for explanation.
2. Package natbib Warning: Citation `mcintyre1952method' on page 1 undefined on input line 5, line 7, etc.

I am using TeXworks 2.9. The structure of my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[msc]{fbe} %withcoadvisor,coadvisorsigne  
\RequirePackage{fontspec}  
\fontspec{Times New Roman}%Times New Roman  
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}%Comic Sans MS  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{enumerate} %for different forms of enumeration  
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}  
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}  
\usepackage{algorithm} %for designing algorithm  
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} %algorithm related  
\usepackage{booktabs} %for toprule, midrule etc.  
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}>


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]  
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}  
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}  



% #########################################  
% ###    Use XeLaTeX     ###  
% #########################################  

% DON'T use inputenc package !!!  
% amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, setspace packages have beeen used. DON'T ADD!  
% natbib ve caption packages have beeen used. DON'T ADD!  

\begin{document}  

....  
\startbibliography  
    \bibliographystyle{plain}  
    \bibliography{mybib}  
....  
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The warning from the `caption` package is probably nothing to worry about since the documentclass you're using loads `caption`. Did you run `bibtex` on the file?  This is probably a duplicate of [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852).

Comment: I did not run bibtex. I only ran XeLaTeX. This is really getting me frustrated as the deadline for submission is fast approaching. Thanks Alan

Comment: It’s the BibTeX program that generates the formatted bibliography. If you don’t run it , no formatted bibliography, and no properly resolved citation call-outs. After running BibTeX, be sure to run XeLaTeX twice more.

Comment: @Mico, running BibTex actually got my computer frozen. additionally, I see a message like 'The style file: fbe.bst. Illegal, another \bibstyle command ---line 121 of  file MyThesis.aux etc.

Comment: I'm guessing here, because we don't have `fbe.cls` (the documentclass you are using) but I suspect that it also comes with its own bibliography style (`fbe.bst`) in which case you need remove your own `\bibliographystyle{plain}` command, delete your `.aux` files and recompile (`xelatex - bibtex - xelatex -xelatex`).  Can you post a link to the document class?

Comment: @Mico It worked eventually, exactly the way you suggested I  run it. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @AbubakrTaylor Was that directed at Mico's comment or mine?

Comment: @AlanMunn, thank you. It worked so well. Indeed, dealing with designed templates can actually be so frustrating! At least, I am done with my thesis now. That is the good news.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I tried both, which both produced the desirable results. Thanks once more.